# How to automatically and randomly reorder custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

Is there a plugin available? Or suggestions on how to achieve re-ordering automatically and randomly custom post type?

Comment: As for the earlier: Theme- or plugin-recommendations are [*off-topic*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. As for the latter: Please include some code, such as your current loop for the CPT. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Or the `pre_get_posts` approach for the CPT archive.... which is more efficient since you don't query twice.

```
function wpa104766_randomize_cpt( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'movie' ) ) {
        // Display custom post type called 'movie' in random order
        set_query_var( 'orderby', 'rand' );
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa104766_randomize_cpt' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just about displaying randomly cpt with a query :

```
<?php
$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type', 
       'orderby' => 'rand'
      );

 $query = new WP_Query($args); 
 if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
// html markup here
<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
```